# How to make 'for loop' skip some iterations in between which shows error?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am running a for loop from (1:1700) in R, but I am loading different data in each iteration. But I am getting error in some iterations in between (may be because of corresponding data is missing).

I want to know if there is any way I could skip those particular iterations in which I get error and at least for loop should complete all the 1700 iterations skipping aforementioned error showing iterations.

I have to run a for loop, there is no other option.

Comment: I contest your last sentence. The answer to your questions are the functions `try` and `tryCatch`.

Comment: If you gave a reproducible example, SO could actually deliberate whether `for` loop is indeed an only choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yoy can use `tryCatch` within your loop. here an example where I loop from 1 to 5 , and for some counter value I get an error ( i create it here using `stop`), I catch it and then I continue for other values of the counters.

```
  for( i in 1:5) ## replace 5 by 1700
     tryCatch({
        if(i %in% c(2,5)) stop(e)
        print(i)   ## imagine you read a file here, or any more complicated process
        }
    ,error = function(e) print(paste(i,'is error')))

[1] 1
[1] "2 is error"
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] "5 is error"
```

Comment: Hey,how do I use it in for loop? Can you please show using a simple for loop? Just how to use it.

Comment: @AyushRajSingh I add an example.

Answer (score 3):

I use `try` for such issues. It allows your loop to continue through the cycle of values without stopping at the error message.

### Example

#### make data

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- vector(mode="list", 1800)
dat
tmp <- sample(1800, 900) # only some elements are filled with data
for(i in seq(tmp)){
    dat[[tmp[i]]] <- rnorm(10)
}
dat
```

#### loop without `try`

```
#gives warning
res <- vector(mode="list", length(dat))
for(i in seq(dat)){
    res[[i]] <- log(dat[[i]]) # warning given when trying to take the log of the NULL element
}
```

#### loop with `try`

```
#cycles through
res <- vector(mode="list", length(dat))
for(i in seq(dat)){
    res[[i]] <- try(log(dat[[i]]), TRUE) # cycles through
}
```